# What is the specification of a degree called?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-meaning, terminology

University degrees are usually specified in some way, so you get, for instance, a bachelor **of arts** or a bachelor **of science**. Now I'm wondering what you call this specification – is there a special word for it, or do you just use a general word such as *specification*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In US English that is the ***name of the degree*** I have never heard it called the "specification". When a degree is abbreviated, the abbreviation always indicates the type and level of the degree in my experience. One might call it the type of degree.

Some examples:

- BA = Bachelor of Arts
- BS = Bachelor of Science
- BN = Bachelor of Nursing
- MB = Bachelor of Medicine (now obsolete)
- LLB = Bachelor of legal Letters (lawyer, now replaced by a JD)
- MA = Master of Arts
- MS = Master of Science
- MFA = Master of Fine Art
- MBA = Master of Business Administration
- PhD = Doctor of Philosophy
- JD = Juris Doctor (Lawyer)
- MD = Doctor of Medicine
- DO = Doctor of Osteopathy
- DDS = Doctor of Dental Surgery

There are others. In some cases the abbreviation is of the Latin name for the degree, such as the JD.

The second element, such as  "of arts" or "of medicine" would essentially never be used alone, so there is no widely used term for it. Even when asking about the type of degree, one might have an exchange such as:

A: "He got a bachelor's degree"
B: "What kind"
A: "He got a BA"

A would never respond just "of arts" in my experience.

I perhaps should mention that my father was a PhD and a college professor, ending his career as a department chairman. My maternal grandfather was also a PhD and Professor, chairing a department for many years. Thus I grew up among things academic to some extent.

Comment: Thank you! I see exactly what you mean – thing is, I'm only after the postmodifying phrases specifying the degree – that is, the phrases "of arts", "of science" etc. "The name of the degree" would refer to the **whole** name, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Helen  Yes, but "of arts" would essentially never be used alone, so there is no widely used term for it. Even when asking about the type of degree, one might have an exchange such as: A: "He got a bachelor's degree" /  B: "What kind" / A: "He got a BA".. A would never responnd "of arts" in my experience.

Comment: Ok, thanks again :) That's exactly what I was wondering – if there is a specific word that you use for it, or if I just refer to it as, for instance, a specification (because I do need to refer to it in a text I'm working on).  Thank you so much for taking your time!

Comment: @Helen, without seeing the context of your writing I think using the word "type" would be more clearly understood than "specification".  It may be worth noting that at many US colleges and universities ther is little or no distinction between a BA and a BS. Which is awarded may depend entirely on the traditions of the school. The courses that at one school would earn a BS at another will result in a BA, The student may have almost exactly the same education.

Comment: Yes, you're right – "type" is better. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the word "faculty" is implicit in most of these - that is "Bachelor of Science" is a short version of "Bachelor's degree awarded by the Faculty of Science".  But it's not idiomatic to ask "[from] which faculty?" if you're asking whether someone has a BA or a BS.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The same is true if British universities. At Oxford and Cambridge, undergraduate studies in almost all sciences, including natural and physical sciences, result in BA (not BSc) degrees. The BAs are also subject to automatic upgrades to MA without any further study. Almost all other UK universities do award BSc for sciences, but there are no exact criteria, so some may give a BA for a course that others would award an MA for, as you said. One difference from the US is that the UK has "BSc" and "MSc", not BS and MS.

Comment: @rjpond Thank you I was aware of the oxbridge practice, but not that of other UK schools. In the US an MS (or MA) will require about 2 years of additional study beyond a BS/BA, and a PhD often 2-3 more beyond that, although that varies a lot. I suspect the practice in India is similar to that in the UK, but that is just a guess on my part.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee  I have seen formal diplomas from a number of US colleges and universities, and none had langue similar "*Bachelor's degree awarded by the Faculty of Science*". That may be used in some places, but I do not not think it is invariable, and even where it is the formal usage, I think just "Bachelor of Science" would be considered the name of the degree.

Comment: I didn't say that was the official name of the degree - I'm saying that the definition of [faculty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faculty) is "a branch of teaching or learning (such as law, medicine, or liberal arts) in an educational institution" and the reason why a degree is called a "bachelor of science" is because it's awarded by that particular branch of teaching (i.e., the faculty of science). I might be influenced by Canadian terminology, which is more fine-grained - for example, you get a B.Eng. (not a BS) from the engineering faculty.